# Update bottomCalc-value, based on selection (if any)

Tags: tabulator

I just found Tabulator, and i love it. I'm currently using version 4.5. The `bottomCalc`-function isuseful, however, i would like it to be updated, based on the `selection` of row(s).

Is there a native option i've missed, or, should it be done manually, fx. triggered by the row-selections?

Column example:

```
                {
                  title: 'Offline Amount',
                  field: 'offline',
                  bottomCalc: 'sum',
                  formatter: 'html',
                  align: 'center',
                  width: 150,
                },
```

And `selectField: true` for `columns`.

*Currenly, without updated bottomCalc:*
[image: Currenly without updated bottomCalc]

And, i would like it to be updated, based on the selection (if **there is** any).

---

**Update**:

I guess the `rowSelectionChanged`-option, will be the best way to handle the update of `.tabulator-footer .tabulator-calcs-holder`, but i'm still unsure about, how to do that part.

If it's a question of looping through the selected values, calculate the sum, and update the value - or if i'm able to use another event, reuse a specific function, or yet another thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in way to achieve this but there may be a work around.

You could store a property in the row data that stores the selected state of the row. You could then use the ***rowSelected*** and ***rowDeselected*** callbacks to change this value.

You could then use a [Custom Calculation Function](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/column-calcs#func-custom) to then generate the sum of the column values for the rows where the data object has a selected property of true.

#### Update

As of version 4.6, there is now a ***recalc*** function you can call on the table, so you could set up your calc function as outlined in the answer above and then use the ***rowSelectionChanged*** callback to trigger the update:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    rowSelectionChanged:function(data, rows){
        table.recalc();
    },
});
```

Comment: You're right. I just hoped that is was created, at some point - and i just missed the option, or maybe, someone had the custom code laying around. I've requested the feature on Github; https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/2545

Comment: Hi again

Thanks for implementing the feature. If other people looking by this question, check out this comment by Oli:
https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/2545#issuecomment-570062723

`table.recalc();` will be added in 4.6 branch.

Thanks!